# How to show posts with at least two categories (in admin)

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, filters, wp-admin

I have a custom post type "cus_type" and and custom taxonomy (category) "cus_category", so that a cus_type can have one or more categories.

In the post list in the admin (edit.php) I want to add a custom filter which, when activated, only shows posts which have at least two categories selected.

My idea was to use the wp filter `parse_query`, detecting if the filter was activated and change something in the WP_Query instance, like `$query->query_vars...`, but nothing worked.